# Python async/await difference in execution time

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I am timing two execution methods using  async io

CASE 1:

```
async def test():    
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'hello'))
    await asyncio.create_task(say_after(4, 'world'))    
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

and it response is :

```
started at 12:31:05
hello
world
finished at 12:31:11
```

a total of 6 seconds

CASE 2:

```
async def test():    
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    t1=asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'hello'))
    t2= asyncio.create_task(say_after(4, 'world'))    
    await t1
    await t2
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

and it response is :

```
started at 12:31:05
hello
world
finished at 12:31:09
```

a total of 4 seconds

why is it so?

Comment: Because the task start to excute when you create it, which means you will have your tasks run in "parallel" if you first create both, then awaits them (since the first task will reach it's pausing condition (`say_after`) directly and then allow next task to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example, you create at ask, wait for it to finish, then create another task, and wait for that other task to finish. You are executing the tasks *sequentially*.

In the second example, you are creating two tasks, then after they are both created, await for the two to finish. You are executing the tasks *concurrently*.

The tasks take up 2 + 4 = 6 seconds to execute one after the other, but when executed consecutively, you only have to wait 4 seconds for the second, longer task to complete while the shorter 2 second task completed some time before then:

```
# sequentially

| start task 1
V
+-------------+
| 2 seconds   |
+-------------+
              ^
await returns |

                | start task 2
                V
                +--------------------------+
                | 4 seconds                |
                +--------------------------+
                                           ^
                             await returns |

# consecutively

| start task 1
V
+-------------+
| 2 seconds   |
+-------------+
              ^
await returns |

| start task 2
V
+--------------------------+
| 4 seconds                |
+--------------------------+
                           ^
             await returns |
```

The difference is calling `asyncio.create_task()` and *not* immediately awaiting on the tasks, because `await task` won't complete until the task has completed.

There is an example in the [*Tasks* section of the *Awaitables* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables):

> ```
> async def main():
>     # Schedule nested() to run soon concurrently
>     # with "main()".
>     task = asyncio.create_task(nested())
>
>     # "task" can now be used to cancel "nested()", or
>     # can simply be awaited to wait until it is complete:
>     await task
> ```

Note the *Schedule nested() to run soon concurrently with "main()"* and *or can simply be awaited on to wait until it is complete* comments.

Tasks are specialised `Future` subclasses, and so the [documentation for `asyncio.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) is relevant here too:

> Future is an awaitable object. Coroutines can await on Future objects until they either have a result or an exception set, or until they are cancelled.

Comment: the documentation should add this, basically `await t1` in case 2 is not needed since `await t2` will wait 4 seconds. Thanks

Comment: @JibinMathews: that's application-dependent, not something the documenation can tell you when to await and when not.